# Azure Datadog eu infra

Tags: azure, datadog, azure-monitoring

I was genuinely interested into deploying datados as a MaaS from the azure marketplace, and I did so just to try how it works. The configuration was extremely easy and I was able to see all the metrics and infrastructure and the `logs` of all my infra.
But the fact that my data leaves EU to get to US, I didn't like it too much. So I was reading that Datadog has a EU infra but you require to have a vm and install the host there.

So I did follow the official documentation and configured:

- Azure Windows VM
- Download and installed the agent
- Once the agent was installed, I configured azure integration
- Created the app registration
- Set the role to `Monitor reader`
- Configured the app service principle in the azure integration in Datadog.

Everything worked just as expected, but when I try to access the logs blade in the left hand side, I don't see any log but instead a initial configuration that needs to be done, like:

- Server
- Container
- Cloud
- Client
- Other

Can please anyone help to understand what I am doing wrong here?
If I want to ingest all the logs from my monitoring (which I have already the permissions set) do I really need to create the event grid, azure function as mentioned under the Cloud section?

I though that the monitoring service principle was more than enough to ingest all the data.

Just out of curiosity, under logs => Server I tried to follow the configurations for .net and enable the logs

```
logs_enabled: true

site: datadoghq.eu
```

and set the sharp Configuration file. but nothing, after restarting the service, I am still unable to receive any log from my subscription.

If anyone can help understand what I am doing wrong here, I would be really grateful.

Please if yo need any extra info, just let me know